# is reliability array keys, which started no alphanumeric and not dash symbols?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this code

```
$arr['... key'] = 'value';
```

this works and not return error, but I interest, how much justified is array keys, like this `'... key'`  ? (here, after points, is space also).  possible obtain some problems, due these keys ?

Comment: A String is a String no matter what you'll put in :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use whatever string you want as a key name. It won't cause any errors or other problems. Weird keys might be hard for you to remember or keep track of, and it's probably not a good idea to use them design-wise, but PHP doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

ok seriously: if you want to use **...** it's fine, any sting is fine, but uncommon, possibly confusing for others, some fonts\screens may render them hard to read - so I wouldn't, but you can if you want to.

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
>   type.
>        Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type.    E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand
>     "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
> - Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be    stored
>     under 8.
> - Bools are cast to integers, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under 1 and the key false under 0.
> - Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
> - Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php